# Referencing a dynamic pivot field using .pivotfields

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I built a macro that I run monthly to generate a pivot table. When using .pivotfields("May-2019 Sales") is there anyway I can reference a specific column instead of "May"? Like .pivotfields("R:R") for example?

I will always be interested in adding the last 4 columns (they are the current month) of the raw data, any other way around this is also appreciated!

```
  With myPivotTable

     With .PivotFields("May-2019 Sales")
       .Orientation = xlRowField
       .Position = 1 
     End with

  End with
```

Comment: You can try something like `PivotFields(wsRawData.Cells(1, "R").Value)` (assuming headers are on Row1 of your data sheet `wsRawData`)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference every PivotField either by its Name or by its index, independent of its usage in the pivottable.

Example:
If your pivottable's source data begins in column "A", then `PivotFields(18)` refers to column "R".

---

`PivotFields(18).SourceName` (or .Name, .Value, .Caption) corresponds to the heading text of its sourcedata column.

---

By this you can check, if a PivotField is used in your pivottable:

```
If .PivotFields(18).Orientation <> xlHidden Then
```